# Oracle data mining : gets SYS.DM_NESTED_NUMERICALS([SYS.DM_NESTED_NUMERICAL]) instead of actual result

Tags: oracle, plsql, data-mining

ORACLE DATA MINING Apriori Algorithm:

```
CREATE VIEW sales_trans_cust_ar AS
  SELECT cust_id,
    CAST(COLLECT(DM_Nested_Numerical(
    prod_name, has_it))
    AS DM_Nested_Numericals) custprods
  FROM sales_trans_cust
  GROUP BY cust_id;
```

After running this query i get the result in custprods columns as SYS.DM_NESTED_NUMERICALS([SYS.DM_NESTED_NUMERICAL], [SYS.DM_NESTED_NUMERICAL]).

But the actual result required was (4,2) in such fashion.

I dont know why it is showing this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Query looks ok. We're using DM_NESTED_NUMERICALS just fine.
The only algorithm that officially doesn't support nested tables is OC clustering.

What version of Oracle is this?